# How to make spec and dummy in ruby gem project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, testing, rspec, rubygems

I'm trying to make my first ruby gem project. This is bootstrap form helper. I do not understand how to properly create spec tests for views (test forms, inputs) and dummy.

In which folder they should be located and how to write tests? Anybody can show a very simple example tests for the forms of views and an example dummy (layout/test app where I can see how it all will look like)?

Comment: Are you using Rails?

Comment: @Skram Yes, it's Rails